# Create element wise dictionary from python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, elementwise-operations

From these arrays:

```
t = ["A","B","C"]
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
```

how can I obtain a list like this

```
[
  { 'A':1, 'B':4, 'C':7},
  { 'A':2, 'B':5, 'C':8},
  { 'A':3, 'B':6, 'C':9},
]
```

so that it is more useful one dumped in JSON?

Comment: Might be worth storing the arrays a,b,c in a named tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
t_data = [a, b, c]
[{u:v for u, v in zip(t, xs)} for xs in zip(*t_data)]
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Is there also an equivalent expression to obtain the opposite?  I.e. from `[ { }, { }, { } ]` to `{'A':[1,2,3 ], 'B' : [4,5,6], 'C' : [ 7,8,9] }` ?

Comment: There is no equivalent expression to get back. In fact, this is another irrelevant question. It'd be better to ask another question.